# Need help making a list work between two class

Tags: c#

Basically I am working on a program that is suppose to replicate a banking program. There are two classes, User and Account. I have the list made in the user account that holds all of the accounts for that user. The list is storing data that is gathered by the Account class constructors. I have been spending many hours reading other people similar problems and it got me up to this point but i am basically stuck an was hoping someone has some suggestions. I am trying to implement the list created in user class to work in account class and think i may need to use an interface or subclass.

```
    class User 
{
    //fields
    private int id;
    public List<Account> _List;


    //properties
    public int Id 
    {
        get { return id; }
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public List<Account> Acc 
    {
        get { return _List; } 

        set { _List = value; } 
    }

    //constructors
    public User()
    {
        _List = new List<Account>();
        Acc = new List<Account>();
    }
    public User(int ident, string name, string username, string password, string account)
    {
        id = ident;
        Name = name;
        Username = username;
        Password = password;
        account = Acc.ToString();
    }


    // methods 

    public void AddAccount()
    {



        Account a = new Account();
        a.Acc = new List<Account>();

        a.Acc.Add(new Account(11111, "Primary Checking Account", 22, 23, "" ));
        a.Acc.Add(new Account(12345, "Primary Savings Account", 22, 23, ""));
        a.Acc.Add(new Account(04587, "Secondary Checking Account", 22, 23,""));
        a.Acc.Add(new Account(00222, "Secondary Savings Account", 22, 23, ""));
        a.Acc.Add(new Account(12457, "College Savings Account", 22, 23, "" ));
        a.Acc.Add(new Account(87442, "Rainy day Checking Account", 22, 23, ""));

    }

    public void DeleteAccount()
    {

    }
    public void ObjectAccount()
    {

    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "null";
    }
```

This is the second class

```
     class Account
{
    //fields

    private int id;
    private string name;

    //properties

    public int Id 
    {
        get { return id; }
    }
    public string Name 
    {
        get { return name; } 
    }
    public int InitialBalance { get; set; }
    public int InterestRate { get; set; }
    public List<Account> Acc
    {
        get { return _List; } // this is where i am having the problem. I cant get the list called _List to exist in the account class.

        set { _List = value; }
    }

    //Constructors
    public Account() 
    {
        _List = new List<Account>();
        Acc = new List<Account>();
    }// this is so the constructor can take 0 arguements.

    public Account(int ident, string nam, int initialBalance, int interestRate, string account)
    {
        name = nam;
        id = ident;
        InitialBalance = initialBalance;
        InterestRate = interestRate;
        account = Acc.ToString();

    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "null";
    }
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper:I think he may asked the best way to implementation

Comment: Why exactly do you have a list of `Account` in the `Account` class? Shouldn't an `Account` have a `User` instead of `List<Account>`?

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a good reason why your Account object needs to have access to the list of accounts that belong to a specific User object.

If you need information about related accounts to perform some action / operation, I would either

- perform those operations from the perspective of the User (where you already have access to the list of accounts - `_List`), or
- create a public method on your User class so that your account object can request a list of related accounts.

  - This doesn't seem very intuitive to me, but I don't know your complete use-case.